# Create specific hyperlinks on search results

Tags: php, html, sql

i'm doing a little web application that works like a little booking.com.

I've written the code for searching the city and I can see the results in a table, how can I make linkable all the results (the name of the hotels for example) and have the redirection to the right hotel page for each result?

I've already tried with  but I had some problem to redirecting to the right page and it gave me some code errors too

```
<?php 

    $con= new mysqli("localhost","root","","registration");
    $name = $_POST['search'];
    //$query = "SELECT * FROM hotels
   // WHERE city LIKE '%{$name}%'";

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hotels
    WHERE city LIKE '%{$name}%'");

echo "
 <table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#111111' width='532' height='23' id='AutoNumber1'>
    <tr>
      <td width='120' height='23' align='center'>Name</td>
      <td width='179' height='23' align='center'>Address</td>
      <td width='100' height='23' align='center'>Phone number</td>
      <td width='150' height='23' align='center'>E-mail</td>
      <td width='50' height='23' align='center'>Stars</td>
      <td width='100' height='23' align='center'>Price single room</td>
      <td width='100' height='23' align='center'>Price double room</td>
    </tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "
    <tr>
      <td width='120' height='23'>$row[namehotel]</td>
      <td width='179' height='23'>$row[address]</td>
      <td width='100' height='23'>$row[phonenumber]</td>
      <td width='150' height='23'>$row[email]</td>
      <td width='50' height='23'>$row[stars]</td>
      <td width='100' height='23'>$row[pricesingle]</td>
      <td width='100' height='23'>$row[pricedouble]</td>

    </tr>";
        echo "<br>";
}
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

In the meanwhile I couldn't create the link, if I have as result for example Hilton, the name should be clickable and it should redirect to the page of the Hilton hotel (created by me in html)

Thank you!

Comment: share the errors .. plz

Comment: What keeps you from printing the relevant markup?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if im understand right.. you need a html hyperlink?

```
echo '<tr>
  <td width="120" height="23">
    <a href="your/target/with'.$row[hotelID].'" >'.$row[namehotel].'</a>
  </td>
  <td width="179" height="23">'.$row[address].'</td>
  <td width="100" height="23">'.$row[phonenumber].'</td>
  ...
  ...
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i was able to create the hyperlink but is it possible to create a different link for every result?

I created the hyperlink with

```
<a href="pagehotel.php"></a>
```

when I create this page I cannot be able to bring the `$_POST['namehotel']`, I have Undefined error

I post the code:

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","registration");


    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hotels
    WHERE namehotel LIKE '%{$_POST['namehotel']}%'");

 mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

How can I have $_POST['namehotel'] from the previous search?